# hibernate table per concrete class @AssociateOverride still using parent attribute to join

Tags: java, hibernate, polymorphism

I implemented hibernate table per concrete class. and my model is as following,

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@TableGenerator(name="baseform", table="BASEFORM_SEQUENCE", allocationSize=1)
public abstract class BaseForm implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="baseform")
    @XmlTransient
    protected Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @JoinColumn(name = "form_id")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @OrderBy("id")
    protected List<CaseNumber> caseNumberList = new ArrayList<CaseNumber>();

    public List<CaseNumber> getCaseNumberList() {
        return caseNumberList;
    }
    public void setCaseNumberList(List<CaseNumber> caseNumberList) {
        this.caseNumberList = caseNumberList;
    }
}
```

I have the following 2 entities extending the BaseForm,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "form_a")
@AssociationOverrides({ 
    @AssociationOverride(name = "caseNumberList", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "forma_id"))
})
public class FormA extends BaseForm  {

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "form_b")
@AssociationOverrides({ 
    @AssociationOverride(name = "caseNumberList", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "formb_id"))
})
public class FormB extends BaseForm {

}
```

Whenever I try to query all the BaseForm and do getCaseNumbersList() it still uses the parent joinColumn and it doesn't apply the AssociateOverride,

```
    List<BaseForm>  baseFormList = new ArrayList<BaseForm>();
    DetachedCriteria baseCR = DetachedCriteria.forClass(BaseForm.class);
    baseCR.add(Restrictions.like("organizationId", orgId, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
    baseCR.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    baseFormList = (List<BaseForm>) ht.findByCriteria(baseCR);
    for(BaseForm form : baseFormList){
            if(!form.getCaseNumbersList().isEmpty()){
                     baseFormList.add(form);
            }
      }
```

I would appreciate if anyone has any idea or fix for that issue?

Comment: Have you tried without specifying the `@JoinColumn` on `BaseForm` ?

Comment: yes I did try. It generates a separate table to do the join.

Comment: Hmm.. you are generating your tables from entities ? And in the tables you have both columns `form_id` and `forma_id`/`formb_id` ?

Comment: yes that's true. the CaseNumber table structure is as following,
id, case_number, forma_id, formb_id, form_id. I tried to get rid of the form_id but I couldn't and it keeps using it instead of using the other ones.